# How can I download high resolution images from google use python + selenium + phantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to fetch more than 100 high resolution images from google, use python2.7 + selenium + PhantomJS.

But since I act like they said, I could only get a webpage with small images on it. And I can't find out any link to the high resolution pictures directly. How could I fix it?

My code is as below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class ImgCrawler:
    def __init__(self,searchlink = None):
        self.link = searchlink
        self.soupheader = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}
        self.scrolldown = None
        self.jsdriver = None

    def getPhantomJSDriver(self):
        self.jsdriver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.jsdriver.get(self.link)

    def scrollDownUsePhatomJS(self, scrolltimes = 1, sleeptime = 10):
        for i in range(scrolltimes):
           self.jsdriver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
           time.sleep(sleeptime)

    def getSoup(self, parser=None):
        print 'a', self.jsdriver.page_source
        return BeautifulSoup(self.jsdriver.page_source, parser)

    def getActualUrl(self, soup=None, flag=None, classflag=None, jsonflaglink=None, jsonflagtype=None):
        actualurl = []
        for a in soup.find_all(flag, {"class": classflag}):
            link = json.loads(a.text)[jsonflaglink]
            filetype = json.loads(a.text)[jsonflagtype]
            detailurl = link + u'.' + filetype
            actualurl.append(detailurl)
        return actualurl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_url = "https://www.google.com.hk/search?safe=strict&hl=zh-CN&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=&bih=&btnG=Google+%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2&q="
    queryword = raw_input()
    query = queryword.split()
    query = '+'.join(query)
    weblink = search_url + query
    img = ImgCrawler(weblink)
    img.getPhantomJSDriver()
    img.scrollDownUsePhatomJS(2,5)
    soup = img.getSoup('html.parser')
    print weblink
    print soup           
    actualurllist = img.getActualUrl(soup,'div','rg_meta','ou','ity')
    print len(actualurllist)
```

Comment: Can you post the shorter code in which you are getting the problem ?

Comment: I'll post the exactlly part of the code if I find out it cause the problem.

Comment: I think it is because the use of PhantomJS. As Dan-Dev post, if use PhantomJS, google send back a very old version web page rather than it use to be. If use the chrome or canary , it will show the normal web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried for a long time to use PhantomJS but ended up using Chrome which is not what you asked for I know, but it works. I could not get it to work with PhantomJS.

First get a driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads you can use a headless version of chrome "Chrome Canary" if you are on Windows.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
import urlparse

class ImgCrawler:
    def __init__(self,searchlink = None):
        self.link = searchlink
        self.soupheader = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}
        self.scrolldown = None
        self.jsdriver = None

    def getPhantomJSDriver(self):
        self.jsdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.jsdriver.get(self.link)

    def scrollDownUsePhatomJS(self, scrolltimes = 1, sleeptime = 10):
        for i in range(scrolltimes):
           self.jsdriver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
           time.sleep(sleeptime)

    def getSoup(self, parser=None):
        print 'a', self.jsdriver.page_source
        return BeautifulSoup(self.jsdriver.page_source, parser)

    def getActualUrl(self, soup=None):
        actualurl = []
        r = re.compile(r"/imgres\?imgurl=")
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=r):
            parsed = urlparse.urlparse(a['href'])
            url = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['imgurl']
            actualurl.append(url)
            print url
        return actualurl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_url = "https://www.google.com.hk/search?safe=strict&hl=zh-CN&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=&bih=&btnG=Google+%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2&q="
    queryword = raw_input()
    query = queryword.split()
    query = '+'.join(query)
    weblink = search_url + query
    img = ImgCrawler(weblink)
    img.getPhantomJSDriver()
    img.scrollDownUsePhatomJS(2,5)
    soup = img.getSoup('html.parser')
    print weblink
    print soup
    actualurllist = img.getActualUrl(soup)
    print len(actualurllist)
```

I changed getActualUrl() to get the image url from an "a" element with a "href" attribute starting with "/imgres?imgurl="

Outputs (when "hazard" is typed in to the terminal):

```
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/article_small/public/thumbnails/image/2016/12/26/16/eden-hazard.jpg']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/EdenHazardDecember_2016.jpg/200px-EdenHazardDecember_2016.jpg']
[u'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/1227/r166293_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc']
[u'https://platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/p42786.png']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Eden_Hazard_-_DK-Chel15_%286%29.jpg/150px-Eden_Hazard_-_DK-Chel15_%286%29.jpg']
[u'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2017/0117/r172004_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/98/c0/eden-hazard-chelsea_1eohde060wvft1elcskrgihxq3.jpg?t=-1500575837&w=620&h=430']
[u'http://e1.365dm.com/17/03/16-9/20/skysports-eden-hazard-chelsea_3918835.jpg?20170331154242']
[u'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2017/0402/r196036_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/nintchdbpict000316361045.jpg?strip=all&w=670&quality=100']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/02/10/14/eden-hazard1.jpg']
[u'http://s.newsweek.com/sites/www.newsweek.com/files/2016/11/07/eden-hazard.jpg']
[u'http://www.newstube24.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/haz.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/17/b1/eden-hazard_68ypnelg3lfd14oxkffztftt6.png?t=-1802977526&w=620&h=430']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/DK-Chel15_%288%29.jpg/220px-DK-Chel15_%288%29.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/omnisport/50/3f/hazard-cropped_3y08vc3ejpua168e9mgvu4mwc.jpg?t=-930203025&w=620&h=430']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nintchdbpict000291621611-e1490777105213.jpg?strip=all&w=745&quality=100']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/01/14/14/Eden-Hazard.jpg']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Eden_Hazard%2713-14.JPG/150px-Eden_Hazard%2713-14.JPG']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nintchdbpict000296311943-e1490777241155.jpg?strip=all&w=596&quality=100']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/01/27/11/hazard.jpg']
[u'http://www.newzimbabwe.com/FCKEditor_Images/Eden-Hazard-896286.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/9c/93/eden-hazard_d4lbib7wdagw1hp2e5gnyov0k.jpg?t=-1763574189&w=620&h=430']
[u'http://www.guoguiyan.com/data/out/94/69914569-hazard-wallpapers.jpg']
[u'http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Football/Pix/pictures/2015/4/16/1429206099512/Eden-Hazard-009.jpg']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/pri_37621532.jpg?w=620&h=406&crop=1']
[u'http://alummata.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Hazard.jpg']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Hazard_vs_Norwich_%28crop%29.jpg/150px-Hazard_vs_Norwich_%28crop%29.jpg']
[u'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/11/06/20/3A185FB800000578-3910886-image-a-46_1478462522592.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/467822629-465742.jpg']
[u'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/10/17/18/2D81CB1D00000578-0-image-a-37_1445102645249.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL_INTERNATIONAL/27/ce/eden-hazard_1kepw6rvweted1hpfmp5xwd5cs.jpg?t=-228379025&w=620&h=430']
[u'http://img.skysports.com/16/12/768x432/skysports-chelsea-manchester-city-eden-hazard_3845204.jpg?20161203162258']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nintchdbpict0003089026162.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'http://www.chelseafc.com/content/cfc/en/homepage/news/boilerplate-config/latest-news/2016/05/hazard--rediscovering-our-form.img.png']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/omnisport/b5/98/hazard-cropped_172u0n8wx4j071cvgs1n3yycvw.jpg?t=2030908123&w=620&h=430']
[u'http://images.indianexpress.com/2016/05/eden-hazard-m.jpg']
[u'http://i2.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article9755579.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/PAY-Chelsea-v-Arsenal-Premier-League.jpg']
[u'http://www.chelseafc.com/content/cfc/en/homepage/news/boilerplate-config/latest-news/2017/06/hazard-injury-update.img.png']
[u'http://futhead.cursecdn.com/static/img/fm/17/players/183277_HAZARDCAM7.png']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/4d/6/eden-hazard-chelsea-06032017_enh1ll3uadj01ocstyopie9e4.jpg?t=-1521106510&w=620&h=430']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/34/8/eden-hazard-chelsea-southampton_1oca1rpy37gmn1ldmqvytti3k4.jpg?t=-1501721805&w=620&h=430']
[u'http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/eden-hazard-of-chelsea-celebrates-scoring-his-sides-third-goal-during-picture-id617452212?s=612x612']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/secondary/Eden-Hazard-889782.jpg']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2015/10/19/16/Hazard.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nintchdbpict000307050894.jpg?strip=all&w=660&quality=100']
[u'http://e1.365dm.com/16/11/16-9/20/skysports-eden-hazard-chelsea-football_3833122.jpg?20161116153005']
[u'http://thumb.besoccer.com/media/img_news/morata-y-hazard--besoccer.jpg']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2017/03/13/21/10-hazard.jpg']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2016/12/27/13/hazard.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/63/2a/eden-hazard-chelsea_15ggj1j39rmky1c5a20oxt3tly.jpg?t=1297762370']
[u'http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article9755531.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Chelsea-v-Arsenal-Premier-League.jpg']
[u'http://cf.c.ooyala.com/l2YmpyYjE6yvLSxGiEebNMr3N1ANS1Xc/O0cEsGv5RdudyPNn4xMDoxOjBnO_4SLA']
[u'http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/eden-hazard-of-chelsea-celebrates-scoring-his-sides-third-goal-during-picture-id617452006?s=612x612']
[u'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2017/0413/r199412_2_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/nintchdbpict000318703991-e1493109803795.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2016/11/18/14/hazard-award.jpg']
[u'http://static.goal.com/2477200/2477282_heroa.jpg']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/12/16/14/eden-hazard.jpg']
[u'http://www.guoguiyan.com/data/out/94/69979129-hazard-wallpapers.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/nintchdbpict0002769424741.jpg?w=960&strip=all']
[u'http://v.uecdn.es/p/110/thumbnail/entry_id/0_ofavjqr8/width/660/cache_st/20170327164629/type/2/bgcolor/000000/0_ofavjqr8.jpg']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/02/07/10/edenhazard.jpg']
[u'http://theworldgame.sbs.com.au/sites/sbs.com.au.theworldgame/files/styles/full/public/images/e/d/eden-hazard-cropped_g6m28ldoc0b41p3f5sp2vlflt.jpg?itok=XW5M7QEA']
[u'http://e0.365dm.com/17/03/16-9/20/skysports-eden-hazard-chelsea_3909051.jpg?20170314181126']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/secondary/Chelsea-Hazard-goals-886084.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/nintchdbpict000319343894.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'https://www.footyrenders.com/render/Eden-Hazard-PL.png']
[u'http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/eden-hazard-of-chelsea-celebrates-as-he-scores-their-first-goal-the-picture-id672946758?s=612x612']
[u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/791664465729163264/XbCVl6BF.jpg']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Eden_Hazard_2011.jpg/170px-Eden_Hazard_2011.jpg']
[u'http://s.newsweek.com/sites/www.newsweek.com/files/2016/02/01/guus-hiddink-says-eden-hazard-could-leave-chelsea..jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/chelsea_hazard_mobile_top.jpg?strip=all&w=750&h=352&crop=1']
[u'http://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/58/photos/735000/Eden-Hazard-887735.jpg']
[u'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03580/Hazard_Real_copy_3580583b.jpg']
[u'https://premierleague-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photo/2017/05/21/47a1f452-43e4-4215-a5b8-5043c1e12a07/686302908.jpg']
[u'http://www.chelseafc.com/content/cfc/en/homepage/news/boilerplate-config/latest-news/2017/06/hazard-s-highlights.img.png']
[u'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/12/14/15/3B45B4D300000578-4032306-Hazard_PFA_Player_of_the_Year_in_2015_has_rediscovered_his_form_-a-6_1481728291902.jpg']
[u'https://img.rasset.ie/000d5137-800.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Eden-Hazard-665260.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Eden-Hazard-659164.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/secondary/Hazard-scored-Chelsea-s-third-goal-against-Tottenham-909804.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/58/photos/237000/Eden-Hazard-887237.jpg']
[u'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/media/motion/ESPNi/2017/0405/int_170405_Hazard_the_successor_to_Ronaldo_at_Real/int_170405_Hazard_the_successor_to_Ronaldo_at_Real.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Eden-Hazard-721522.jpg']
[u'http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/eden-hazard-of-chelsea-celebrates-with-teammates-after-scoring-his-picture-id633776492?s=612x612']
[u'http://betinmalta.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/hazard.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/58/photos/708000/Eden-Hazard-Chelsea-712708.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/omnisport/c9/4a/eden-hazard-cropped_12u5irb6bkze1cue2wpjzxa44.jpg?t=-2084914038&w=620&h=430']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nintchdbpict0003291256741.jpg?strip=all&w=714&quality=100']
[u'https://premierleague-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photo/2017/03/10/f97d36aa-1eef-4a78-996f-63d543c79efc/700017169TS004_Eden_Hazard_.JPG']
[u'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f0/01/17/f001178defb2b3be3cffb5e9b792748b--eden-hazard-liverpool-england.jpg']
[u'http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article9898829.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/hazard-2.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/24/76/eden-hazard-and-lionel-messi_kamv8simc20x1p2i2fcf7lllw.png?t=421166242&w=620&h=430']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/gettyimages-618471206.jpg?w=748&h=498&crop=1']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Hazard-Chelsea-658138.jpg']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/04/23/17/hazard.jpg']
[u'http://e0.365dm.com/15/10/16-9/20/eden-hazard-comparison-chelsea_3365521.jpg?20151018152317']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/galleries/x701/231048.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/galleries/x701/102742.jpg']
[u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GWhVkFTe_BY/maxresdefault.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/nintchdbpict000319343748-e1496260888520.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/689818982.jpg?w=748&h=498&crop=1']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nintchdbpict000308902470.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/nintchdbpict000289569836.jpg?w=960&strip=all']
[u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zZ9stt70_vU/maxresdefault.jpg']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Kylian_Hazard_%28cropped%29.jpg']
[u'http://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2017/03/26/14905092504845.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/omnisport/ba/47/eden-hazard-cropped_rccnpv1me3v51kqpnj5ak4nko.jpg?t=1222186324&w=620&h=430']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/secondary/Eden-Hazard-922505.jpg']
[u'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/48/ce/4c/48ce4c478d8b06dccacce352d9d4bdc2--eden-hazard-pogba.jpg']
[u'http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/football/2016/10/23/111897755_Editorial_use_only_No_merchandising_For_Football_images_FA_and_Premier_League_restrict-large_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqqVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwfSVWeZ_vEN7c6bHu2jJnT8.jpg']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/686902184.jpg?w=748&h=652&crop=1']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nintchdbpict0003086723271-e1489501904590.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'http://e2.365dm.com/17/01/16-9/20/skysports-chelsea-manchester-city-eden-hazard_3862340.jpg?20170406190414']
[u'http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/football/2017/05/26/TELEMMGLPICT000129483487-large_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqajCpFXsei0OXjDFGPZkcdJOkVdu-K0ystYH4SV7DHn8.jpeg']
[u'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FFE4Ea437ks/maxresdefault.jpg']
[u'https://i1.wp.com/www.vanguardngr.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Hazard-madrid.png?resize=350%2C200']
[u'http://china.chelseafc.com/content/cfc/zh/homepage/teams/first-team/eden-hazard/summary/_jcr_content/tabparmain/box/box/textimage/image.img.jpg/1496846329140.jpg']
[u'http://static.goal.com/198700/198707_news.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/nintchdbpict000319357531.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/eden-hazard-of-chelsea-poses-with-the-premier-league-trophy-after-the-picture-id686826640?s=612x612']
[u'http://cf.c.ooyala.com/t3dXdzYjE6VJktcnKdi7F2205I_mSSKQ/eWNh-8akTAF2kj8X4xMDoxOjBnO_4SLA']
[u'http://c.smimg.net/16/39/300x225/eden-hazard.jpg']
[u'http://www.whatfootballersearn.com/wp-content/uploads/Eden-Hazard.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/58/photos/328000/Eden-Hazard-437328.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/secondary/Eden-Hazard-Chelsea-882846.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Chelsea-star-Eden-Hazard-741161.jpg']
[u'https://talksport.com/sites/default/files/styles/taxonomy-img/public/field/image/201703/hazard_0.jpg']
[u'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/08/28/21/37A101A700000578-3762573-image-a-19_1472417354943.jpg']
[u'http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/football/2016/07/27/87650659-edenhazard-sport-large_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqqVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwfSVWeZ_vEN7c6bHu2jJnT8.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/58/photos/165000/620x/Eden-Hazard-598896.jpg']
[u'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/05/04/21/33C8A26600000578-0-image-a-19_1462392130112.jpg']
[u'https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/13AA1/production/_96354508_595836d4-f21a-419b-95cb-37a65204f6eb.jpg']
[u'https://premierleague-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photo/2016/11/30/1eb421ae-b210-4a01-95bb-36f509826cc1/Debruyne_v_Hazard.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nintchdbpict000309639487-e1490040388851.jpg?strip=all&w=739&quality=100']
[u'http://static.goal.com/3311200/3311292_heroa.jpg']
[u'http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7986781.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Hazard-and-son.jpg']
[u'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/0916/r126535_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc']
[u'http://www.chelseafc.com/content/cfc/en/homepage/news/boilerplate-config/latest-news/2017/03/hazard-score-is-number-one-.img.png']
[u'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2015/03/17/13/eden-hazard.jpg']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/680506564.jpg?w=748&h=457&crop=1']
[u'http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/eden-hazard-of-chelsea-celebrates-with-diego-costa-of-chelsea-after-picture-id671559962?s=612x612']
[u'http://e0.365dm.com/17/05/16-9/20/skysports-eden-hazard-chelsea_3965489.jpg?20170529101357']
[u'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e0/80/0e/e0800e380ef363594fb292969b7c5b64--eden-hazard-chelsea-soccer.jpg']
[u'http://cdn-football365.365.co.za/content/uploads/2016/12/GettyImages.630542828.jpg']
[u'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/07/16/19/340E4A9A00000578-3693637-image-a-84_1468694248523.jpg']
[u'http://www.squawka.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/hazard-chelsea-e1485528066609.jpg']
[u'http://www.guoguiyan.com/data/out/94/68880901-hazard-wallpapers.jpg']
[u'http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/football/2017/03/12/JS122962983_EHazDavid-Rose-large_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqtA9hvt4yaDuJhaJG2frTIUNrh1MdssoHpGF6OIxC49c.jpg']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL/17/25/eden-hazard-chelsea_1dsnlf2z113cx10nxvp9ydudcz.jpg?t=2008335075']
[u'http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/football/2016/12/05/115182685-eden-hazard-sport-large_trans_NvBQzQNjv4BqA7a2BP2KFPtZUOepzpZgXISdNn8DgVUcalGVREaviFE.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/sport-preview-morata-hazard.jpg?strip=all&quality=100&w=750&h=500&crop=1']
[u'http://thumb.besoccer.com/media/img_news/eden-hazard--futbolista-del-chelsea--chelseafc.jpg']
[u'http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7374471.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/Chelsea-Training-Session.jpg']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/671549404.jpg?w=748&h=532&crop=1']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/462363538.jpg?w=748&h=563&crop=1']
[u'https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/6834221661.jpg?w=748&h=507&crop=1']
[u'http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/590x/Chelsea-star-Eden-Hazard-739447.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.quotesgram.com/img/21/41/114220036-24CA6E4700000578-2916442-Eden_Hazard_has_been_instrumental_for_Chelsea_this_season_as_the-a-7_1421682779132.jpg']
[u'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/09/29/09/38E4401500000578-3813294-image-a-1_1475138637248.jpg']
[u'http://healthyceleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Eden-Hazard-match-between-Chelsea-Milton-Keynes-Dons-January-2016.jpg']
[u'https://talksport.com/sites/default/files/styles/taxonomy-img/public/field/image/201704/gettyimages-663029916.jpg']
[u'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/Thorgan_Hazard_2014.jpg/220px-Thorgan_Hazard_2014.jpg']
[u'http://cdn.images.dailystar.co.uk/dynamic/58/photos/91000/620x/Eden-Hazard-632850.jpg']
[u'http://i4.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7531141.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/A-dejected-looking-Eden-Hazard.jpg']
[u'https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/nintchdbpict000322464448-e1494602676644.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100']
[u'http://images.performgroup.com/di/library/GOAL_INTERNATIONAL/76/92/chelsea-bournemouth-eden-hazard_148j4p900kzba159diso6ewwvo.jpg?t=1004329665&w=620&h=430']
[u'https://images.cdn.fourfourtwo.com/sites/fourfourtwo.com/files/styles/inline-image/public/hazard3.jpg?itok=ap0DtuZx']
[u'https://talksport.com/sites/default/files/styles/taxonomy-img/public/field/image/201707/hazard.jpg']
...
[u'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2017/0330/r195127_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=738&site=espnfc']
299
```

Comment: Thank u for help. I will try to find out if it is ok to use Chrome.

Comment: Have a look at https://duo.com/blog/driving-headless-chrome-with-python

Comment: Thanks. I have read the page. But I think it is for MacOS, not for Win.  I got another tips at http://www.cnblogs.com/roystime/p/7117515.html. And now it works.